GetFeatureInfo value_list converting long numbers to rounded exponents
I have a multiband GeoTIFF that I'm serving up as a WMS. Doing a GetFeatureInfo request works fine, except for the ID of the pixel, which is the first band.
Somehow MapServer is converting the 10 digit number to a 8 digit exponent, thus missing off the last digits. Does anyone know how to force MapServer to write out all values in full?
Here is my mapfile:
MAP
  IMAGETYPE PNG24
  NAME "map_file"
  EXTENT -180 -90 180 90

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    DRIVER "GD/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    NAME "png24"
  END

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wfs_title" "WFS Server"
      "wfs_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
      "wfs_enable_request" "*"

      "wms_title" "WMS Server"
      "wms_enable_request" "GetMap GetCapabilities GetLegendGraphic GetFeatureInfo"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
    END
  END

  LAYER
    NAME "map_layer"
    EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
    STATUS ON
    TYPE RASTER
    PROCESSING "BANDS=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" 
    PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=AVERAGE"
    DATA "/file.tif"
    TEMPLATE "text.htm"
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:4326"
    END
    METADATA
      "wms_title"         "forecast"
      "wms_include_items" "value_list"
      "wms_getfeatureinfo_formatlist" "text/plain,application/vnd.ogc.gml,gml"
      "gml_include_items" "all"
    END
  END #layer
END


Just curious, does it do it for all output formats?

You could try "gml_types" "auto" to your LAYER METADATA:
    METADATA
      "wms_title"         "forecast"
      "wms_include_items" "value_list"
      "wms_getfeatureinfo_formatlist" "text/plain,application/vnd.ogc.gml,gml"
      "gml_include_items" "all"
      "gml_types" "auto" 
    END

For vector layers you can override the default types, but I'm not sure if this works for raster:
"gml_value_0_type" "long"


thanks, tried that but it didn't work.
